# Function returns "Array" instead of actual output

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function returnArray() { 
    $intData = array("1", "3"); 
    return $intData[array_rand($intData)]; 
}
```

I'm trying to make a function similar to the one above.

Instead of adding integers with commas I'm trying to implode the commas with the integers.

Sort of like a dynamic version of the above using `json_decode`, `file_get_contents`, a `foreach` loop, `array`, `array_rand` & `return`

This is my code:

```
function Something() {
  foreach (json_decode(file_get_contents('removed'), true) as $jsonArr) {
    $arrData = array(implode(",", $jsonArr));
    $roundData = $arrData[array_rand($arrData)];
    return $roundData;
  }
}
```

I was just wondering if I'm doing it right and if the array is correct or not.

Also it doesn't return anything from the `array`.

When I try to implode, it throws an error

> implode invalid argument

Comment: "doing it right", is something you should be telling us

Comment: This is just basic debugging you can do yourself, I don't see an actual *problem* in your question.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to be returning anything from the array.

Comment: What's the purpose of this function?

Comment: It's supposed to return an integer from the array. But it doesn't.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what is going on in your function. from what array it should return integer? what if `file_get_contents` failed? And many more...

Comment: Everything works fine, it's just that it doesn't return anything, also it throws errors `invalid argument` while `imploding`.

Comment: @user2524169: Are you trying to get all the `room_id` from your JSON and display a random `room_id`?

Comment: Yes exactly but in the array();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to print a random `room_id` from the JSON response.

The problem lies here:

```
$intData = array(implode(",", $arrRoomsReverse['room_id']));
```

You can't initialize an array like that.

Just push the `room_id` element to the array, like so:

```
$intData[] = $arrRoomsReverse['room_id'];
```

Now, you can simply get a random `room_id` outside the loop:

```
$intRoom = $intData[array_rand($intData)];
```

The function would look like:

```
function returnArray() 
{
    $str = file_get_contents('...');
    $jsonArr = json_decode($str, true);
    foreach ($jsonArr as $arrRoomsReverse) 
    {
        $intData[] = $arrRoomsReverse['room_id'];
    }
    $intRoom = $intData[array_rand($intData)];
    return $intRoom;
}
```

And to call the function:

```
echo returnArray();
```